# Category and subcategory in url Custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I added cpt and custom taxonomy. I writed function in my functions.php which adding in my url, category and subcategory then my url is "mysite.com/house/category/subcategory/post_name". Url show but not working, because show message "page not found". If I delete category in my url or subcategory this single page showing. Please help me! My code:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'projectcategory_permalink_structure', 10, 4);
function projectcategory_permalink_structure($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample) {
    if (false !== strpos($post_link, '%kategorie_dladomu%')) {
        $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'kategorie_dladomu');

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            if ( $terms->parent == 0 ){
                $category = $term->slug;
                foreach( $terms as $subterms ){
                    if ( $subterms->parent == $term->term_id ){
                        $subcategory = $subterms->slug;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $slug = "$category/$subcategory";
        if ( ! empty( $slug ) ) {
            return str_replace( '%kategorie_dladomu%' , $slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```